# sequence definition of proper group action

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions

My understanding is that for an action by a Lie group $G$ on a second countable and Hausdorff differentiable manifold $M$ to be proper, it suffices to show that the map $G \times M \rightarrow M \times M$ is closed with respect to prescribed topologies on these spaces and that the fibers are compact. No local compactness is assumed here for either $G$ or $M$. One way to do so is to prove that given a sequence $\{g_n\}$ in $G$ and a converging sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $M$, if the sequence $\{g_n \cdot x_n\}$ converges in $M$, then $\{g_n\}$ contains a converging subsequence.

I have searched places I could think of including posts at this site but could not seem to find any example that actually uses this sequence characterization to prove properness of a group action. When I tried to take this approach myself, I quickly became clueless about exactly how to actually find a converging subsequence for $\{g_n\}$. Naively, my attempts often involved looking for a compact (hence sequentially compact given metrizability) subset in $G$ into which $\{g_n\}$ eventually fall. However, it did not turn out to be easy (to me, at least) to cook up an apporopriate compact subset. In particular, I had little luck utilizing the triangle inequality for I was unable to estimate the rate of convergence for $\{g_n\}$. In my poor man's analysis toolkit, the next and perhaps the last in line would be Ascoli theorem when, in special cases, certain space(s) of interest turned out to be compact; it seemed to me though that the subsequence given by Ascoli converges only in $C^0$ and thus might not always match the desired topology in the given scenario.

I am just beginning to learn this material, could someone kindly provide or point me to some less trivial and representative example(s) illustrating necessary procedures to arrive at a converging subsequence in the differentiable context?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since $M$ and $G$ are differentiable manifolds, what do you mean when saying that they are not necessarily locally compact? Are you working with infinite-dimensional manifolds? If so, what definition you use? Also, shouldn't it be $G \times M \to M$ instead of $G \times M \to M \times M$?

Comment: I simply did not need to exclude infinite-dimensional groups and manifolds such as those modeled on Hilbert spaces. For the extended map, my understanding is that the properness follows from the closedness of the orbit relation as a subset in $M \times M$, which the sequence characterization is designed to show.

Comment: So, is the map $(g,x) \mapsto (gx, x)$?

Comment: Can you please edit little bit so that actual question is written separately.. This is just my personal request.. I am not able to read that long paragraph..

Comment: The characterization in terms of sequences is often used in infinite dimensions. For example, the proof that the group of gauge transformations on the space of connections is proper uses sequences (see, eg, Narasimhan and  Ramadas. “Geometry of SU(2) gauge ﬁelds”)

Comment: Mr. Diez -- thank you! This is an excellent example. It is a very fortunate situation where SU(2) is compact, which enables the extraction of a point-wise converging subsequence to begin with. I am still digesting Lemma 2.6 to see how the continuous dependence of the initial value problem for y on parameters implies uniform convergence on compacta...